# Add CSS to ScalaHelpers

Tags: css, forms, scala, playframework

How do i add some CSS to the Scala Helpers, and is it possible to remove the "Required" and "Numeric" text under the textfield?

[image]

```
@inputText(advForm("weeknr"))
@inputText(advForm("jaar"))
@inputText(advForm("datum"))
```

--------------------EDIT 1------------------

When I add my own CSS, im not getting the error warnings that i used to get when I try to upload an empty form, the text used to turn red. This is the code I changed

MyPlainFieldConstructor.scala.html(only 2 lines of code):

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)
@elements.input
```

advPlaatsen2.scala.html:

Added this line of code

```
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myPlainFieldConstructor.f) }
```

and this is how i placed the CSS(Foundation 5):

```
<div class="row collapse">
 <div class="small-2 columns">
    <span class="prefix">Email</span>
 </div>
 <div class="small-4 left columns">
    @inputText(advForm("email"),
    'id -> "right-label",
    'placeholder -> "")
 </div>
</div>
```

This way the forms looks how I want it to look but it doesnt show me errors and it doesnt even upload my files

[image: Form]

but when i remove this line of code:(which is above the @import helper._)

```
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myPlainFieldConstructor.f) }
```

the form works as it should but looks really bad:

[image]

Comment: "Looks really bad". I like the way you describe what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customize the html and styles of a field you can write your own field constructor. Take a look to play docs [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaFormHelpers#Writing-your-own-field-constructor).

Comment: can you help me with the problem ran up against? I made changes in the Post